# Get decimal numbers using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry for the noob question.

```
var regex = ??
var a = '<span class="star" id="1.00"></span>';
var number = a.match(regex);
```

How can I get the 1.00 using regex?

Thanks for the help..

Comment: why dont you directly use the span tag and extract the id using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var regex = /id\="(\d+(\.\d+)?)"/i;
var a = '<span class="star" id="1.00"></span>';
var number = a.match(regex); 
 alert(number[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Forexample:

```
var regex = /[0-9\.]+/;
var a = '<span class="star" id="1.00"></span>';
var number = a.match(regex);

alert(number);
```

Comment: this will match also <span class="star" bobo="1.00"></span>

Comment: This will return `5` if input text is `<span class="star5" id="1.00"></span>`

Comment: @Royi Namir: Sure, it was only regex example for this case. If I use your `/id\="(\d+(\.\d+)?)"/i` below, it takes eg. `<div class=xy id="1.00">`, etc. He has a string without `bobo` attribute, wioth no additional numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var a = '<span class="star" id="1.00"></span>';
var m = a.match( /\bid=(["']?)([^"']+)\1/i );
var id;
if (m) 
    id = m[2]; // 1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO using regex wont solve your problem, you should first craete an html element from the string and then get the id.

```
var s = '<span class="star" id="1.00"></span>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;
var element = div.firstChild;

console.log(element.getAttribute("id"))
```

output:

```
1.00
```